# Why does this integral count zeros and poles?

Tags: complex-analysis

I have a few questions about the theorem below.

First of all, is it assumed that all poles and zeros are simple? (Otherwise it would be natural to expect the orders of zeros and poles appearing somewhere in the formula.) What is meant by "we choose the representative zeros and poles inside $P_a$"? Does it mean that we translate the fundamental parallelogram $P_a$ so that it contains $a_i$ and $b_j$ for $i,j=1,\dots, n$? If so, I understand why it is possible to do for poles (which are located at the vertices of the lattice $M$), but why it is possible to do also for zeros? (I.e., to enclosed all $a_i$'s and $b_j$'s to one $P_a$? Further, I do not understand why the integral in the proof equals the sum of $a_i$'s and $b_j$'s. How does it follow from the calculus of residues? This integral resembles the integral from the Argument Principle, but it's not quite that integral.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a fundamental domain there are only finitely many zeros and poles,
so one may translate the period parallelogram to avoid all of them.

This sum
adds poles and zeros according to multiplicity, so if $a$ is a double
zero, one gets $2a$ in the sum, and if $b$ is a treble pole one gets $-3b$ in the sum.

To see this, assume $f$ has order $k$ at a point $a$, then $f(z)=(z-a)^kg(z)$ where $g$ is holomorphic and $g(a)\ne0$. Then $(f'/f)(z)
=k/(z-a)+(g'/g)(z)$ and $z(f'/f)(z)=kz/(z-a)+z(g'/g)(z)$ has residue
$ka$ at $a$, etc.